# Why does the listVIew go behind EditText?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

Hey People I have the problem that when the listview grows, it goes behind the editText... I do not want it to go behind the view.. I want it to stay over the editText.. could you help me ? I appreciate your Help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"></ListView>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom"
            android:hint="Type text here..."
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxEms="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="insertTo"
            />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Its not going behind the `editText`, its the last limit of text to scroll at end of `listview` boundary.

Comment: it's not going behind. It is default behaviour as your main layout is linear layout and childs are being aligned vertically. It is shown like that due to paddingBottom in listview

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Changed the **weight** of the views

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"></ListView>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom"
            android:hint="Type text here..."
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxEms="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="insertTo"
            />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove:** `android:layout_weight="1"` from **ListView**

**It Looks Like:**

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout as the root view of your xml.

Give the GridLayout an id, and make it alignParentBottom="true". Keep your ListView above the GridLayout. What it should look like is:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gridviewItem">
</ListView>

and GridView item should look like: 

<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridviewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:columnCount="2">
```

// Grid View items
/>

hope this helps....